# Electromagnetic interaction of a scalar field before KK reduction

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, kaluza-klein

Consider the following gravitational action in $d+1$ accompanied with a complex scalar field $\chi$ with a mass $m$:

$$S=\int d^{d+1}x\sqrt{-\tilde{g}}\left[\tilde{R}+\tilde{g}^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\chi}\partial_\nu\tilde{\chi}-m^2\chi\chi^*   \right]$$
How does the fact that the scalar field is charged under the gauge field that appears in the reduced $d$ dimensional action manifest in the $d+1$ action?

after KK reduction the action becomes:
$$S=2\pi R\int d^dx\sqrt{-g}e^\sigma\left[R-\frac{1}{4}e^{2\sigma}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+\partial_{\mu}\sigma\partial^{\mu}\sigma 
 +{g}^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}{\chi}\partial_\nu{\chi}-m^2\chi\chi^*\right]$$

So what should I add to the $d+1$ dimensional action to have eventually the $d$ dimensional action:
$$S=2\pi R\int d^dx\sqrt{-g}e^\sigma\left[R-\frac{1}{4}e^{2\sigma}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+\partial_{\mu}\sigma\partial^{\mu}\sigma 
 +{g}^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}{\chi}\partial_\nu{\chi}-m^2\chi\chi^*+iq\left(\chi^* A^\mu\partial_\mu\chi-\chi A_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\chi^* \right) -q^2A_\mu A^\mu\chi\chi^*\right]$$